# FileNotFoundException: src\main (Access is denied)

Tags: java, windows, nullpointerexception

I am going to index files in a folder:

```
 public static final String FILES_TO_INDEX_DIRECTORY = "src/";

 File dir = new File(FILES_TO_INDEX_DIRECTORY);   //ERROR
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
...
```

But I got getting this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main
>   (Access is denied)    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)

My project is in the desktop:

`C:\Users\hamed\Desktop\SearchEngine`

Comment: try with absolute path and see the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which line causes the FileNotFoundException?   If I try your code, the line marked `// ERROR` always works, both with valid as well as with non-existent file names.

I suspect the exception happens in a later line (which you have not given in your snippet).

It may actually really be what the error message says (access denied).

Check the file permissions.  It can be tricky on Windows, when copying the files from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

When building the Drools examples in Eclipse (Win7), I had Access Denied build errors like:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\opta\drools-distribution-7.7.0.Final\examples\sources\.classpath (Access is denied)
```

Checking file `.classpath` turned out to have hidden attribute set in Win7.

Unchecking the hidden attribute brought me to the next build error for `.project`.

Also hidden, and unchecking that gave immediate build success.

Comment: @Grant: thank you for taking the trouble making my answer more readable!

Comment: No problem at all!